# how to convert form response to html

Tags: php, json

Following is my form html code:

```
<form action="mysite.com/searchNum" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="say">Number</label>
        <input name="num" id="num" value="">
    </div>`
    <div>
        <button>Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form I get something like this:

```
{
    "message": "Successfully retrived",
    "error": false,
    "result": [{
        "id": 6128071,
        "name": "jhon doe",
        "number": "31231231230",
        "city": "C",
        "cnic": "8982378237897278",
        "address": "address123",
        "activation_date": "0"
    }]
}
```

How do I show response data in following format and show on other page

```
(data.html):<br>
Name : ___<br>
Number: ______<br>
Cnic: ________<br>
Address : ________<br>
activation date: _______
```

Comment: That question is a little broad. You tagged php so what does your PHP file look like and what have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Use your `$_POST` variable. It's just an array which can be looped, or accessed via individual elements, such as `$_POST['message']` and so on. But you have a json string? So to access that you can follow these examples:

Now you have a json string you could simply:

```
$json_string = '{
    "message": "Successfully retrived",
    "error": false,
    "result": [{
        "id": 6128071,
        "name": "jhon doe",
        "number": "31231231230",
        "city": "C",
        "cnic": "8982378237897278",
        "address": "address123",
        "activation_date": "0"
    }]
}';
```

Then decode the json file into an array:

```
$json_array = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

The json string becomes an associative array:

```
Array
(
    [message] => Successfully retrived
    [error] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6128071
                    [name] => jhon doe
                    [number] => 31231231230
                    [city] => C
                    [cnic] => 8982378237897278
                    [address] => address123
                    [activation_date] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Which, then can be accessed like this:

```
echo $json_array['message'];
```

---

Now for what you are trying to achieve simply do this:

```
Name : <?=$json_array['result']['name']?><br>
Number: <?=$json_array['result']['number']?><br>
Cnic: <?=$json_array['result']['cnic']?><br>
Address : <?=$json_array['result']['address']?><br>
activation date: <?=$json_array['result']['activation_date']?>
```

Comment: Thanks. but how do i show this on other page. When user click submits button it should send him to page like data.html

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand. When you post the form what are you doing?

Comment: when user clicks submit then search result is showed . how i show this result to other page

Comment: when user click submit it sends him to http://mysite/searchNum but i want that when user click submit it send him to data.html where data is shown.

Comment: Change the form `action` to `data.html`?

Comment: form must submit to mysite/searchNum but show responce from  mysite/searchNum to data.html

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include what you are doing in `searchNum`?

Comment: So you are posting to a third-party laravel site? I am not sure I know how to help you bud...